# What does (1U << X) do?

Tags: c++

I found this piece of code:

```
enum 
{
  IsDynamic = (1U << 0),  // ...
  IsSharable = (1U << 1), // ...
  IsStrong = (1U << 2)    // ...
};
```

What does the `(1U << X)` do?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It sets bitmasks:

```
1U << 0 = 1
1U << 1 = 2
1U << 2 = 4
etc...
```

What happens is 1U (unsigned value 1) is shifted to the left by x bits.

The code you posted is equivalent to:

```
enum 
{
      IsDynamic = 1U,  // binary: 00000000000000000000000000000001
      IsSharable = 2U, // binary: 00000000000000000000000000000010
      IsStrong = 4U    // binary: 00000000000000000000000000000100
}
```

Comment: Are you not missing a zero on IsStrong = 4U    // binary: 00000000000000000000000000000100? 

4U -> 4th bit not 3rd

Comment: 4U is not the 4th bit but the value `4`. U denotes that it's an unsigned int.
`1U << 2` --> binary `100` --> int `4` --> U denotes unsigned int `4U`.

Answer (score 5):

Bit shift. Instead of saying a = 1, b = 2, c = 4 they shift the bits.
The idea is to pack many flags into one integer (or long).

This is actually a very clean approach.

Answer (score 2):

<< is the bitshift operator. It will take the bits in the left side and shift them by an amount specified by the right side. For example:

```
1 << 1    -> 0b0001 << 1     =>   0b0010  
1 << 2    -> 0b0001 << 2     =>   0b0100
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

`1U` is an unsigned value with the single bit 0 set, and all the other bits cleared.  The `<<` operator means "shift to the left".  `1U << 0` means create a value with bit 0 set; `1U << 1` means create a value with bit 1 set; etc.

Answer (score 0):

That snippet

```
enum 
{
      IsDynamic = (1U << 0),  // ...
      IsSharable = (1U << 1), // ...
      IsStrong = (1U << 2)    // ...
}
```

declares an enumeration with values which are powers of 2. To be used presumably as masks on a value which contains multiple flags.

So for example a value representing something that IsDynamic and IsSharable is

```
unsigned value = IsDynamic | IsSharable; // could use + as well
```

And to test if the value IsStrong

```
if (value & IsStrong) { ... }
```