# How to handle fast insert-erase operations in this c++ data structure?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

**Fact:** my code is in c++

**Question:**

I have a list of *unsigned long long*, which I use as reppresentation for some objects and the position in the list is the ID for the object.

Each unsigned long long is a sort of lis that mark if an object has the component j, so let say that I have

```
OBJ=1 | (1<<3)
```

that means that the object has the components 1 and 3.

I want to be fast when I insert, erease and when I retrieve objects from the list. 
The retrieve usually is performed by components so I will look for objects with the same components.

I was using std::vector but as soon I started thinking about performance it seems to me not to be the best choice, since each time I have to delete an object from the list it will relocate all the object ( erease can be really frequent ) plus as soon as the underlying array is full vector will create a new bigger array and will copy all the elements on it. 
I was thinking to have an "efficientArray" wich is a simple array but each time an element is removed I will "mark" the position as free an I will store that position inside a list of available positions, and anytime I have to add a new element I will store it in the first available position. 
In this way all the elements will be stored in contiguos area, as using vector, but I avoid the "erease" problem.

In this way I'm not avoiding the "resize" problem (maybe I can't) plus the objects with the same components will not be closer (maybe).

Are there other ideas/structures wich I can use in order to have better performance?

Am I wrong when I say that I want "similar" object to be closer?

Thanks!

EDIT

Sorry maybe the title and the question was not write in a good way. I know vector is efficient and I don't want to write a better vector. Since I'm learning I would like to understand if vector IN THIS CASE is good or bad and why, if I'm wrong and if what I was thinking is bad and why, if there are better solutions and data structures (tree? map?), if yes why. I asked even if it is convinient to keep "similar" objects closer and if that MAYBE can influence things like branch prediction or something else (no answer about that) or if it is just nonsence. I just want to learn, even "wrong" answer can be useful for me and for others to learn something, but seems it was a bad idea like I asked *"my compiler works even if I write char ** which is wrong"* and I didn't understand why.

Comment: If you think that a `list` is too slow or you need random access, then how about a `deque`?

Comment: "Fact: my code is in c++"  I don't know why, but that made my day.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" Donald Knuth

Comment: "In established engineering disciplines a 12% improvement, easily obtained, is never considered marginal and I believe the same viewpoint should prevail in software engineering" -Donald Knuth

Comment: @Surt it's amazing that you can tell that there is a 12% or higher performance difference between one implementation and the other in an early stage of development, specially not knowing the system.

Comment: You can't arithmetically OR the values 1 and 3, because the answer is 3.  You can't tell if object 1 exists or not when object 3 exists.  The proper function is `(1 << object_number)`, such as `(1 << 1) | (1 << 3)`.

Comment: @RyanP "my code is in c++" if I was using Java or phyton or some other language maybe I should think in a different way, maybe but I'm asking because I don't know so the language can be a useful information.

Comment: @imreal "I was using std::vector but as soon I started thinking about performance it seems to me not to be the best choice..." this sentence can maybe let you imagine that I'm not thinking on optimizzation in a premature way but I have some code and I want to improve it

Comment: How many total components do you have to deal with? Are the numbers dense? That is: if you have component numbers from one to, say, a million, does that mean that every, or nearly every, number in that range is meaningful, or do you have a large range of numbers of which only a few are used?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  thank you but 1U is not the same as (1<<1) and 3U (1<<3)?

Comment: @imreal, I can't say it 100% but my experience is that vector works better in most cases, so using vector as a first implementation is not bad as it is using prior work as a foundation.

Comment: _"I'm not thinking on optimizzation in a premature way"_ - Did you profile it? Is there an actual bottleneck in your code? If not the optimization is premature.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't know how many components the object will have but I have the constrain that each object can have a maximum of 64 components as I'm using long long

Comment: @GCC I understand that it is important to write optimal code right from the start using good practices, but other than minding complexity, don't "fix" code that you haven't profiled.

Comment: @GGC: if you only have to keep track of (Yes|No) for 64 objects, `std::bitset<64>` may interest you.

Comment: @GGC: In binary, the value 3 is 0011.  In binary, the value 1 is 0001.  Note that with each case there is a 1 in the right most digit.  The arithmetic OR works in binary.  The value (1 << 3) is 1000 in binary, completely different than 0011.  Research binary arithmetic.

Comment: @GGC: Also worth noting, vectors don't work how you think they do.  They _move_ when an element is moved, they don't reallocate.  And it turns out that moving `unsigned long long` is _really_ fast.    Your "efficientArray" is pretty much guaranteed to be slower for lookups and inserts, and only fractionally faster at deletion.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128442/what-does-1u-x-do

Comment: @mooingDuck why my array is slower for insertion? It not depend on how I trace the free space?

Comment: @GGC: Yes: You have to trace the free space.  Vector doesn't.  The majority of the time, inserting a item at the end of a vector is merely storing one number, increment one number, and it's done.  If you preallocated via reserve, then that's 100% of the time.  Even when shifting, it can simply memmove, which will probably outperform any clever tricks with 'free' marks.  Add to that the fact that vector was written by world professionals, and tested over thousands of man-hours.

Comment: @GCC - Moving an unsigned long long takes about 1 nanosecond. That is 0.000000001 second. And you think that is too slow??

Comment: @BoPersson I don't think it is too slow I'm just asking if there is a better solution but maybe I didn't write it in a good way, even if I cant read a sentence "is too slow" or "is a bad idea" any sentence start with "for me" "maybe" I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the 
wheel I know that vector has been made by very good developer,but  since what I'm doing I'm doing it for LEARNING I don't think it's a bad idead to think about everything even vector, that maybe has been made to perform good in most of the case but not in every case. I'm sorry and I don't want to criticize anybody but I would really apprectiate if you can explain me better if I'm wrong and why insted of judge. Thank you!

Comment: @GCC - You say *"I want to be fast"*, and a vector *is* fast. Actually extremely fast in many cases. People often mistake `O(n)` to be worse than `O(1)`, but that is not true if `n` * nanoseconds is compared to `1` * milliseconds. The value of `n` has to be HUGE before you have to leave the vector as a first choice.

Comment: @BoPersson "fast in many case" I know that's what I'm asking is this the case? If yes why? if no why?...anyway thank you for your answer :)

Comment: I reworded a little bit your question, maybe it has a better chance to reopen.

Comment: @thomasmatthews sorry I was totally wrong and stupid you are right! :)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using either `std::set` or `std::map`.  You want to know if an item exists in a container and both `std::set` and `std::map` have good performance for searches and "lookups".

You could use `std::bitset` and assign each object an ID that is a power of 2.

In any case, you need to profile.  Profile your code without changes.  Profile your code using different data structures.  Choose the data structure with the best performance.

Comment: In C++ `std::set` and `std::map` is not hashes like you might expect from other languages. You have to use the `unordered_*` versions for hashes. It does depend on what is causing the most slowdown. The BST versions could be better if those provide the operations you need, otherwise some other implementation might be better. +1 for suggesting actually profiling.

Answer (score 1):

Some timing for different structures can be read [here](http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2014/05/cpp-benchmarks-vector-vs-list-vs-deque/).

The problem with lists are that your always hunting after the link, where each link potentially is a cache miss (and maybe a TLB miss in addition).
The vector on the other hand will enjoy few cache misses and the hardware prefetcher will work optimally for this data structure.
If the data was much larger the results are not so clearcut.

Comment: yes cache miss is one of the problems I was thinking about, another problem is branch prediction that's why I want to keep "similar" object closer